# SQLite JDBC rs.getDate() getTimestamp() etc. all return wrong values

Tags: sqlite, datetime, date, jdbc, timestamp

When using the JDBC for SQLite for some reason Date and Timestamp values are stored correctly in the DB, are displayed correctly when using the command line sqlite3 tool, but when using the ResultSet functions to retrieve these values it doesn't work. Below is a small test class that demonstrates what I mean.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
    Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
    stat.executeUpdate("drop table if exists people;");
    stat.executeUpdate("create table people (name, occupation, date date);");
stat.executeUpdate("insert into people values ('Turing', 'Computers', date('now'));");

    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from people;");
    while (rs.next()) {
      System.out.println("name = " + rs.getString("name"));
      System.out.println("job = " + rs.getString("occupation"));
      System.out.println("date = " + rs.getDate("date"));
      System.out.println("dateAsString = " + rs.getString("date"));
    }
    rs.close();
    conn.close();
  }
}
```

The output I get is:

name = Turing 
job = Computers 
date = 1970-01-01 
dateAsString = 2011-03-24

Comment: stat.executeUpdate("create table people (name, occupation, date date);");

Try to name the "date" field with anything else than "date"?

Comment: @Redger I did try that, and it didn't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like Scott says: SQLite does not have a Date type.

You could have SQLite do the conversion for you with the [strftime](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) function: `strftime('%s', date)`.  Then you can use `rs.getDate` on the Java side.

You can also retrieve the SQLite date as string, and parse that into a date:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
try {
    Date today = df.parse(rs.getString("date"));
    System.out.println("Today = " + df.format(today));
} catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That was the solution I came up with, but it looked pretty hacky (I was assuming something better was available "natively"). I guess I'll have to stick with this.

Comment: Any clue how I could force the date to be stored as an integer (unix time stamp) instead of a string? I could use Int type instead of Date, but can I specify I want Date to be stored as Int?

Comment: When using setDate and getDate, JDBC.SQLite [automatically stores it](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/dates.html) as a 64-bit long of milliseconds since epoch start.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite3 does not have a Date type so you will have to get the String of the dates when writing your code.

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 2):

SQLite does not use 'types' and instead uses what's known as 'type affinity';

From the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#section_3) itself:

> The important idea here is that the type is recommended, not required

You can store the dates as strings and parse them however you like with formatting classes like `SimpleDateFormat` or `DateTimeFormatter`, or you can use something crude like `Date.from(Instant.parse(rs.getString("date")))`.

### Java 8

Amongst the other answers here, I'd say that `LocalDate#parse()` and `LocalDateTime#parse()` is also a good option for Java 8 moving forwards.

They accept a date in String format

`LocalDate.parse("2016-05-24")`

Or a String with a DateTimeFormatter as the second argument

`LocalDate.parse("2016-05-24", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(yyyy-MM-dd))`

---

### Conversion

And if you're looking to use `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` but want to support `Date`, maybe in an **adapter pattern**;

### LocalDateTime to Date:

This example uses the system default timezone as the ZoneId argument of atZone, however you can use a static/hard-coded timezone if you want to. Essentially you are creating an Instant from AtZone which can be used to build a Date from the static method `Date#from(Instant)`

```
Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
```

### LocalDate To Date:

This example is pretty much the same, only here all that's required to get a ZoneId in order to create an Instant is the `LocalDate` instance itself.

```
Date.from(localDate.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
```

---

I've not gone into technical detail here, it may not even be necessary, but do correct me if I'm wrong.