# SQL statement does not give local time when execute through jsp

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jsp, jdbc

When I execute SQL statement "SELECT datetime('now', 'localtime')" from a stand-alone JDBC program against SQLite JDBC driver, I get correct local timestamp whereas when I execute it through a JSP page, I get GMT/UTC time. Could somebody explain why I am getting UTC time in case of JSP code? I wanted local time as given by the stand-along program. I have made sure that both use the same JDBC driver jar file "sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar".

Here is the stand-alone SQLite JDBC program:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class GetTimestamp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement p = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); 
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/db1", null, null);
            p  = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT datetime('now', 'localtime')");
            rs = p.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("Current timestamp = " + rs.getString(1));
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + se.toString());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + cnfe.toString());
        }
    }    
}
```

Its output:

[image: Standalone program o/p]

Here is the equivalent JSP:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>  
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement p = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); 
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/db1", null, null);
        p  = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT datetime('now', 'localtime')");
        rs = p.executeQuery();
        //System.out.println("Current timestamp = " + rs.getString(1));
        out.println("Current timestamp = " + rs.getString(1));
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        //System.out.println("Error: " + se.toString());
        out.println("Error: " + se.toString());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        //System.out.println("Error: " + cnfe.toString());
        out.println("Error: " + cnfe.toString());
    }
%>
</BODY>
</HTML
```

Its output is
[image: jsp o/p]

Comment: For the love of code, **always close your ResultSet, Statement/PreparedStatement and, finally, Connection** in a `finally` block. It might not be necessary in Java 6 and upwards (on some classes) but it's best programming practice.

Comment: Have you tried using `rs.getDate` and a `SimpleDateFormat`? As you have it you are relying on way too many possible variables.

Comment: Buhake Sindi, thanks for your suggestions. The code I mentioned is only to demonstrate the problem and not part of final code which will take care of the points you mentioned.

Comment: OldCurmudgeon, I need timestamp and not just date. I tried the following methods rs.geTring(1) is the most closest one except that it does not give time with offset 5.30 from GMT: rs.getDate(1).toString() = 1970-01-01 
rs.getTime(1).toString() = 05:30:00 
rs.getTimestamp(1).toString() = 1970-01-01 05:30:00.0 
rs.getString(1) = 2014-08-27 05:18:06

Comment: what version of SQLLite did you use?

Comment: It is 3.6.23.1 as reported by getDatabaseProductVersion(). Driver jar file is sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar.

Comment: OldCurmudgeon, SimpleDateFormat solves one of my problems! Thank you. Still I need to make the SQL stmt work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when we are using the implicit object `out` in our scriplets, it doesn't generate pure output like our System.out, since it is a type of `javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter`, so, it generates HTML and not pure output.

So, with this information, i assume this object is wrapping your information in a way you don't want.

You will probably have to output it in another way, like using tag setTimeZone as Corey said, here is an example:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>JSTL fmt:setTimeZone Tag</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:set var="now" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />
<p>Date in Current Zone: <fmt:formatDate value="${now}" 
             type="both" timeStyle="long" dateStyle="long" /></p>
<p>Change Time Zone to GMT-8</p>
<fmt:setTimeZone value="GMT-8" />
<p>Date in Changed Zone: <fmt:formatDate value="${now}" 
             type="both" timeStyle="long" dateStyle="long" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bruno, I am passing String object to out.println() method and hence the the method is not likely to know if the passed String object is a timestamp/datetime object.  I do not use tags like "c:set" in my JSP pages. When I tried your code no values were displayed as part <P> tags. Do I need to install something else along with Tomcat web server in order to make your code work?

Comment: I am looking for a solution without using taglibs. Some suggested setting timezone environment variables for Java using Tomcat configuration tool or directly editing windows registry. But so far no luck.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425557/sqlite-jdbc-rs-getdate-gettimestamp-etc-all-return-wrong-values). SQLLite doesn't have [Date type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so you need to get the String of it using `rs.getString(1);`

Try this.

```
 <%
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement p = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); 
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/db1", null, null);
            p  = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT datetime('now', 'localtime')");
            rs = p.executeQuery();

            //System.out.println("Current timestamp = " + rs.getString(1));
            DateFormat converter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date queryDate = converter.parse(rs.getString(1));
            out.println("Current timestamp = " + converter.format(queryDate));

            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            //System.out.println("Error: " + se.toString());
            out.println("Error: " + se.toString());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            //System.out.println("Error: " + cnfe.toString());
            out.println("Error: " + cnfe.toString());
        }catch(ParseException e){
            out.println("ParseError: " + e.toString());
        }
    %>
```

Not sure if this helps.

Comment: No problem as long as it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the timezone? Wild guess, so I hope it helps...

```
<fmt:setTimeZone value="GMT+10" /> //Set to whatever your timezone is
```

I'm not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I came up with a workaround based on input from all of you. Basically, it gets timezone info, get its offset, add the offset to the timestamp value queried from SQLite.
Of course there is a bit danger in the workaround when SQLite JDBC driver starts giving correct value in future!

```
<HTML>
<BODY>  
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.text.*"%>
<%
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement p = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    // Get current timezone and find offset from UTC.
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    out.println("<BR>Current timezone=" + timeZone);
    long offset = timeZone.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis());
    out.println("<BR>Timezone offset=" + offset);

    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC"); 
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/db1", null, null);
        p  = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT datetime('now', 'localtime')");
        rs = p.executeQuery();

        // Convert queried timestamp to Java Date object.
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        java.util.Date queryDate = sdf.parse(rs.getString(1));
        out.println("<BR>timestamp from SQLite = " + sdf.format(queryDate));

        // Get localtime by adding time zone offset.
        long tm = queryDate.getTime() + offset; // New time with offset.
        java.util.Date newDate = new java.util.Date(tm);
        out.println("<BR>timestamp with timezone offset= " + sdf.format(newDate));

        rs.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        //System.out.println("Error: " + se.toString());
        out.println("Error: " + se.toString());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        //System.out.println("Error: " + cnfe.toString());
        out.println("Error: " + cnfe.toString());
    }

%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Here is the o/p:

[image]