# Java dataparse error from SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, date, resultset

I am having an error when I try to retrieve data from my SQLite database.

[image]

It retrieves the first row of data onto the table but when the date is there it gives the error shown below.

This is the code where I am getting the error.

```
try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Rooms.db");
        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        pst = con.prepareStatement("Select * from Standard");
        rs = pst.executeQuery();


        while (rs.next())
        {
            LocalDate sD = null;
            LocalDate eD = null;
            if (rs.getDate(6) != null)
            {
                sD = Conv(rs.getDate(6));
                eD = Conv(rs.getDate(7));
                System.out.println(sD + "   " + eD);

                if (chkIn.getValue().isBefore(sD) == true && chkOut.getValue().isBefore(eD) == true)
                {
                    datas.add(new StandardRoomList(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2) , "£" + (rs.getInt(3)*pri), "" + rs.getInt(4)));
                }

            }
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-11-17" does not match (\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q \E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q.\E(\p{Nd}++)
at org.sqlite.date.FastDateParser.parse(FastDateParser.java:299)
at org.sqlite.date.FastDateFormat.parse(FastDateFormat.java:490)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getDate(JDBC3ResultSet.java:293)
... 64 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern in the error message implies that the JDBC driver is expecting a string of the form "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.milliseconds".  That's not compatible with the date representation from your database.

The fundamental problem here is that SQLite doesn't support date / time / timestamp types:

- [SQLite JDBC rs.getDate() getTimestamp() etc. all return wrong values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425557/sqlite-jdbc-rs-getdate-gettimestamp-etc-all-return-wrong-values)

You appear to have encoded your dates as strings in your database, and it appears that the JDBC driver is attempting to convert those string values to date / time values using a built-in heuristic.  But that is failing.

I suggest that use getString to retrieve the values from the results-set and then do the string -> date conversion explicitly using Java's built-in date / time classes.

Another approach would be to change the JDBC driver's default date-time format using an `org.sqlite.SQLiteConfig` object.  However, I can't find any documentation for this approach ... apart from the source code!